# Cannot select Oracle table from other Server with schema name prefix

Tags: oracle

Few days ago there was network problems. Also one of the database harddisk partition storage ran out of space but it has been fixed now.
Additional note: one of the DBA compressed the archive log to spare some space during the problem happened.

One of the outcome was that now I CANNOT select one table from other Oracle database on the other server if using schema name prefix.

For example if I run query from one of the schema/user in database1 from Toad or sqlplus:

```
select * from office.room@database2
```

The query runs forever and never stops.
Usually it's not a problem. The other tables are fine; I can select them using office.*@database2 query.

The other odd thing is that if I use SYNONYM, I CAN select that table. Let's say that table has synonym 'room' on db2 database, this query is OK:

```
select * from room@database2
```

The table itself on database2 is OK, meaning that if I login to schema "office" on database database2, I can select the table data.

I still can not find out what causes this problem.

New founding, I can select the table with no hang up if I add WHERE filter or I select the columns, for example :

```
select * from office.room@database2 where roomnumber='A';
```

or

```
select roomname, rumnumber from office.room@database2;
```

But the select * from office.room@database2 still hang up.

Comment: Can you post the execution plans for both queries?  Make sure to include the "Notes" section.  There might be a plan management feature, like a SQL Profile, that's only being applied to one of the queries.  Are you sure these are plain tables, and not views?  It's unusual for querying a table to take a long time.  But there are some rare reasons that can happen, such as dynamic sampling.

Comment: The explain plan for both queries are the same :

Comment: SELECT STATEMENT REMOTE ALL_ROWS
- TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE schema.table_name dblink

Comment: Yes, it is plain table, not a view. I wonder why adding the schema prefix makes the query hang up or neverending, where usually it's not a problem. And why only this table.

Comment: Is it possible the table was accidentally re-created in the DB_LINK user's schema, and the queries are accessing different tables?

Comment: @JonHeller No, it isn't.